# SQL Server query very slow, how can I improve speed?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables, regarding certain items which require regular inspection:

```
Collections  
-Id

CollectionItems (ie, the individual items within a group of items)  
-Id  
-Name  
-CollectionId  
-NotAvailable  
-LastInspectionDate

ItemReports (inspection reports on items)  
-Id  
-CollectionItemId  
-ReportDate
```

I want to display a list of all items within a collection.
One of the columns shown should be the most recent inspection date of the item.

However, this date needs to be the last ACTUAL inspection date, not the date an inspection was last attempted.

- If the engineer goes to look at the collection and one item can't be found, the reason (ID) is put into the "NotAvailable" field. No report is created.
- If the item is found, NotAvailable will be 0 and a report will be created.

`LastInspectionDate` in the `CollectionItems` table is updated regardless of whether the item was found or not.

So I want the last `ReportDate`, and if no reports exist then I want the `LastInspectionDate`.

The query I have is basically:

```
SELECT 
    CollectionItems.*,
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ItemReports.NotAvailable = 0 THEN ReportDate END), 
    CollectionItems.LastInspectionDate) AS LastActualDate
FROM 
    CollectionItems
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemReports ON ItemReports.CollectionItemID = CollectionItems.Id
```

This works fine, but is very slow. On a collection of 300+ items this can take well over 30 seconds.

How can I improve the performance of this, ideally in one query?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the `ItemReports` table? What you could do is include the actual execution plan of the query you're trying to run and see what operation takes the longest to complete (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/analyze-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: How can anything takes 30 seconds when you're working on 300 items, what are you not telling? How big is ItemReports and what kind of indexes do you have on it

Comment: Doh. Execution plan is useful thanks, didn't know about that. Anyway, added the recommended index to the report table and the query is now pretty much instant. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: @siggemannen
The report table has nearly 500k records. Anyway I didn't have any indexes apart from primary key so that's sorted now... oops

Comment: @Sparrowhawk, one should always share the execution plan when asking SQL Server performance. Keep in mind that missing indexes are suggestions, not recommendations, so they should be implemented judiciously.

Comment: Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show tables and index definitions.

Comment: You are probably going to want an index `ItemReports (CollectionItemId, NotAvailable, ReportDate)` to make this efficient.

Comment: @Charlieface That's exactly what I did - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the query plan it's difficult to say, but you are probably going to want an index to make this efficient. Either a clustered or non-clustered index will do.

```
ItemReports (CollectionItemId, NotAvailable, ReportDate)
```

I would assume `CollectionItems.Id` is a clustered primary key, if not then you should make it seo

Answer (score 0):

First selects the maximum report date for each item where the item is available (NotAvailable = 0) using a subquery. Then, it joins this result with the main CollectionItems table, using LEFT JOIN to ensure all items are included, regardless of whether there is a matching report or not. Finally, it uses COALESCE to select the last actual inspection date, either from the maximum report date or from the LastInspectionDate column if no reports exist for the item.

```
SELECT 
    CI.*,
    COALESCE(IR.LastReportDate, CI.LastInspectionDate) AS LastActualDate
FROM 
    CollectionItems CI
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        CollectionItemId,
        MAX(ReportDate) AS LastReportDate
    FROM 
        ItemReports
    WHERE 
        NotAvailable = 0
    GROUP BY 
        CollectionItemId
) IR ON CI.Id = IR.CollectionItemId;
```

Comment: Thanks - this helps a bit, but not enough! In my test case it takes it from 47 down to 36 seconds, better but still far too long.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is just if you assume it most likely is an index that is needed, but you have trouble finding the right index:

In SQL Server management studio mark the code and choose "Analyse Query in Database engine tuning advisor. (install developer edition if you have express).

Then you click analyse and it will come with a suggestion that will use some disk space. If you are ok with this just apply it.

Answer (score -1):

try using this code.,

```
SELECT CollectionItems.*,
           MAX(CASE WHEN ItemReports.NotAvailable = 0 THEN ReportDate END) AS LastActualDate
FROM CollectionItems
LEFT JOIN ItemReports ON ItemReports.CollectionItemID = CollectionItems.Id
GROUP BY CollectionItems.Id;
```